# How to use ifstream to input a file into a 2D array?

Tags: c++

I'm struggling on overloading the `ifstream` operator to get an input from a file in a matrix form and creating a 2D array. This is for a 3x3 matrix. This is a small part of an assignment without which my whole assignment is quite pointless.

file example:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 6
```

Comment: Sorry the file example was supposed to be a 3x3 matrix

Comment: Please show us what you've tried first.

Comment: I agree. This is too simple; it seems you didn't do any tests whatsoever, or you'd already have found out how to read that.

Comment: Can you please search first.  There are too many posts already.

Comment: I found a bunch of examples by using these keywords: `stackoverflow c++ read file matrix 2d array`

Answer (score 1):

I have done this way...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int data[3][3];
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  ifstream in(filename);
  std::string line;
  std::string temp;
  while(std::getline(in, line))
  {
      std::istringstream iss(line);

      // Parse each line using the input string stream
      j = 0;
      while(std::getline(iss,temp,' '))
      {
         data[i][j] = std::stoi(temp);
         j++;
      }
      i++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```